# Unable to run Django with a MySQL backend

Tags: mysql, django

I'm trying to setup Django with a MySQL backend, previously I've only used sqlite, and I've got a rather odd error. `Error was: No module named mysql.base`

I'm running Ubuntu with Nginx and uwsgi, and I have python-mysqldb installed. And following this I've started to get a 502 so I hope thats related because I've not changed any config files.

Here is the stacktrace following `manage.py inspectdb`;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 453, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 272, in fetch_command
klass = load_command_class(app_name, subcommand)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 77, in load_command_class
module = import_module('%s.management.commands.%s' % (app_name, name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
__import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/inspectdb.py", line 8, in <module>
from django.db import connections, DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 40, in <module>
backend = load_backend(connection.settings_dict['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 34, in __getattr__
return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 93, in __getitem__
backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 45, in load_backend
raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'django.db.backends.mysql' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named mysql.base
```

Db settings;

```
  DATABASES = {
      'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
            'NAME': 'wdsdj',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3
            # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
            'USER': 'mark',
            'PASSWORD': 'pass',
            'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
            'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
      }
  }
```

If I change to sqlite3 then I get no problems from dj;

```
# This is an auto-generated Django model module.
# You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
#     * Rearrange models' order
#     * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
# Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
#
# Also note: You'll have to insert the output of 'django-admin.py sqlcustom [appname]'
# into your database.
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
```

Comment: do you have the mysql-python binding installed ? `sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb`

Comment: Can we see your setting file for the DB?

Comment: duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6132181/importerror-no-module-named-mysql-base-in-django-project-on-ubuntu-11-04-serve), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15611085/mysql-python-django-1-5-0-no-module-named-mysql-base-error), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10020157/django-mysql-error), etc.

Comment: @danodonovan I've been through those and they do not fix this. I already have my settings set as they should be as far as I am aware. I'll update with them.

Answer (score 1):

Check your settings make sure ENGINE is correct `django.db.backends.mysql`.

Then make sure you have installed python-mysqldb...

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

However, in your error stack it states '`isn't an available database backend`' seems like something could be wrong with your Django installation, maybe?

Comment: The engine is correct (see OP) and I have python-mysqldb already. (import MySQLdb works in python). I'm running Django 1.5.1 final which I have installed in the past few days.

Comment: I see, well I have only seen this error once here: https://github.com/gmcguire/django-db-pool/issues/5 something has to be misconfigured

Comment: Thanks, I'll check those out after work :) Maybe at this early stage I should give PostgreSQL a go, I've never used it before so was going to go with MySQL.

Comment: I switched to PostgreSQL and it's working just fine. Much simpler than MySQL.